# create table cells similar to the ones in the iTunes store

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, ios5

I was wondering what is the best way to create cells similar to the ones in the iTunes store with the play icon on the side.

Here is an image

http://www.blogcdn.com/www.tuaw.com/media/2008/04/newiphoneads_itunes_store_12739.jpg

Thanks, 
Ross

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a UITableViewCell subclass and add some subviews, there are no built-in playing buttons like the itunes store one though, so you might have to create that yourself too.

Comment: Here is a great example of doing so.All the others are using xib which is not really used that often in iOS 5. 

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3zhn_R-jtw